# How can we verify the font color using tosca

Tags: tosca

Can anyone help me to verify the font color using tosca application.
As we are using tosca for mobile automation and we are unable to verify the font color used in the mobile application. If anyone help us to identify the font color on web application, Even that would help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tricentis Knowledge Base has an article on [Verifying HTML Styles (CSS)](https://support-hub.tricentis.com/open?id=kb_article_view&sys_kb_id=c65b29bbdbccff8899529eb1ca9619d3) that might cover what you need.